# Размер блока, в зависимости от размера экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такой функционал:
В зависимости от ширины экрана, блок будет менять свои значение.
Но!, есть нюанс - Имею блок с огромной шириной: .slides = 25000px.
Размер .wrapper и .slider = 100%
Размер экрана будет 1500px
Нужно чтобы бралось значение 1500px и применялось к классу .slide

```
<div id="slider" class="slider">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="slides" class="slides">
   <div class="slide">
     <H4>Slide 1</H4>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ширина экрана - это `width: 100vw;` (**V**iewport **W**idth)

Comment: Если вообще ни чего не писать в css а в  html вписать только div он будет 100%  ширины

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот если я вас правильно понял

```
.slide{
   width:100vw;
}
```

Уже вижу вопрос в ваших глазах , "что за такая единица измерения vw".

vw - относительная единица измерения блока ,1vw эквивалентно 1% ширины окна браузера. Т.е. если взять 100vw , то блок будет размером 100% окна браузера.

***Важно помнить, что это vw берёт не размер экрана , а именно размер окна браузера.***